# C++ WinInet no second request

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

I'm currently coding a website watcher, witch calls every minute a website and parses the new threads. Because I only need the HTTP I just used the WinInet-API. Everything works, but than I saw that the second request (and following requests) is always empty. Also the forum/site doesn't log a second visit.
I have no clue what happened. I set no cache and I'm closing everything at the end.

The code is:

```
char *getRequest(wchar_t *url)
{
    HINTERNET hInet = InternetOpen(L"MyBrowser", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (!hInet)
    {
        processError(L"Error getRequest 1");
        return 0;
    }
    HINTERNET hUrl = InternetOpenUrl(hInet, url, NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE, 0);
    if (!hUrl)
    {
        processError(L"Error getRequest 2");
        InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
        return 0;
    }
    DWORD dwNumberOfBytesRead = 0;
    char *ret = (char*)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 4096);
    if (!InternetReadFile(hUrl, ret, 4096, &dwNumberOfBytesRead))
    {
        processError(L"Error getRequest 3");
        InternetCloseHandle(hUrl);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
        LocalFree(ret);
        return 0;
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(hUrl);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
    return ret;
}
```

At wireshark there is no connection too.
Thank you!

Comment: There is no way to diagnose your problem with the limited information you have provided. There is nothing wrong with the code you showed, so it has to be a problem with the code you did not show. Assuming no errors are being reported, the most logical explanation is that your other code is likely not calling `getRequest()` when you are expecting it to.

Comment: while (1)
    {
        char *req = getRequest("url");
        /* Do something with req */
    }